# SQL Server Query to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-server

We have developed a set of operational reports long back ago based on the SQL server , Currently we have added a third party source which has Oracle as source and we need to modify our existing SQL queries to pull the partial data from oracle as well. The tricky part of the requirement is we have different table from different source belong to single query 
for example

```
SELECT A.ID , B.Name 
  FROM A --Belong to SQL server
 INNER JOIN B --Belong to Oracle server 
    On A.id=B.id
```

I know we can have a linked server facility in SQL which allows us to grab the table B in some temp table and then join the SQL table with the temp table.

I just want to know is there any better approach to accomplish this as this would be very difficult to deal with the complex queries in case of this , Specially the sub queries and recursive queries.

Is creating a staging table with all required field from oracle and then use it in queries makes sense? as we are dealing with the operational data (though in most of the cases it is 1 day old,So we can do this).

We are using SSIS,SSRS and SQL serer 2008 R2 as development environment.

Thanks.

Comment: It would depend on how much data you are getting from Oracle. If it's not much, then I would use a temp table to hold the Oracle data. Otherwise the staging table that's populated by an SSIS job would be the better way to go. How much is too much? That depends on how much data, how fast the connection is etc. If putting the data in a temp table takes more than a couple of seconds then I would use SSIS.

Comment: The data will be not huge , But it will be a transcational data, So it is like duplicating it in environment. How about creating the views with OpenSQL?

Comment: You should be able to get away with just using a view that cuts down the data that you're getting from Oracle directly in your query. If it runs too slow, then you can try dumping the results of the view into a **#temp** table and referencing the temp table in your query.